# Can every efficiently computable permutation be written as the composition of two efficiently computable involutions?

Tags: circuit-complexity, permutations

It is well-known that every permutation can be written as the composition of two involutions.

Suppose that $p$ is a polynomial. Then does there exist a polynomial $q$ such that if $f:\{0,1\}^{n}\rightarrow\{0,1\}^{n}$ and its inverse are permutations which are computable by combinatorial circuits with at most $p(n)$ gates, then there exists involutions $g,h:\{0,1\}^{n}\rightarrow\{0,1\}^{n}$ such that $f=g\circ h$ and where $g,h$ are computable by a combinatorial circuit with at most $q(n)$ gates?

Comment: for the lazy, an easy proof the fact mentioned in the post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951314/composition-of-2-involutions